# Buttons not being affected by bootstraps col-md

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, forms, button

I have what I think is a very basic problem but to which I cannot find the solution. So I have a form in my rails project. I want to create an input field, and two buttons associated with that field so I can add another type of input field.

[image]

If I click on the green button, I append another set of the same 3 fields.

```
<div class="col-md-2">
      <%= f.input :select1, collection: @traffic_vault.sort + [["------ Aggregations ------ ", ""]] + @traffic_vault_aggregations.sort, include_blank: false, label: "Select Dimensions (*)", input_html: {class: "remember_timestamp", type: "text" } %>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="apply_function(0)">Apply Function</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="rename(0)">Rename It</button>
</div>
```

My problem is that the input field is working fine by taking exactly the col-md that I put there, but the buttons are not, they are taking slightly less space, not exactly col-md-2. So, when adding more fields to the first image, since the buttons are not exactly col-md-2, I get this:

[image]

I found out the problem is with the buttons because if I change it to inputs, it is working perfectly.

[image]

As we can see, they all have the same space between them, and each of them is col-md-2, so when adding 6 of these fields, you have col-md-12, so anymore fields added will be placed below and so on, but not with the buttons.

What is the problem?

[image]

solution: thanks to Siim for the answer. By placing style="width:100%;" button will take all available width. But still, i have a problem where, even if the buttons are col-md-2, like the inputs from before, if i add a 3rd set of fields, its not being placed correctly like in the 3rd image with the inputs, where the new set is placed at the beginning of another row.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `w-100` class to the button. This tells the button to take up 100% of the available space.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label>
      <input class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
        btn
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success w-100">
        btn
      </button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Reading now my comment sorry if i sounded mean xD. For some reason w-100 was not working but style="width:100%" works, so thanks! I still have a problem, my buttons are same size as the inputs, but if i add a 3rd set of fields with these buttons, its not working like in the 3rd image, although they are same size.

Comment: Check your resulting html. I suspect your new col-md-whatever is ending up inside another col-md-something not beside it inside the row.

Comment: My new col-md is not inside another col, i already tried this before, but i delete it, the resulting html is just 3 divs with col-md-2, inside another div that DOESN't have col-md. If i use inputs, is working. but if i use buttons, it is not, like the last image that i put here, so im kind of confused. Buttons and inputs are same size, but with buttons, when adding another col-md-6 to a row that already has col-md-12, it places it very weird below the last element.